# How to use Meteor settings.json when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: meteor, heroku, google-api

In development, I use `meteor --settings settings-development.json`. Also I have a file named settings-production.json, but I don`t want to get this file on github. I want Heroku to use this file when deploying. How can I do that?

Asked, because since I use service-configuration package, when I deployed on heroku, app crashing...

Comment: `heroku config:add METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"` doesn`t help

Comment: did you give it the path to *your* `settings.json` (i.e, `settings-production.json`)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I synced my heroku with a dropbox folder and I need to start using settings.json as well.